# Order by surname not working for names like O'Brien and O'Koren

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a custom field of surname and I have the following query to get them, it shows that it orders them by the meta key 'last_name'

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'team-member',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'last_name',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
```

The expected order should be O'Brien then O'Koren, but it's doing it in the other order. With these queries does it just stop when it hits punctuation in a string?

Comment: Do you need to order by 'meta_key' or 'meta_value'? Currently you are ordering by 'meta_value' but the last name seems to be on 'meta_key'

Comment: Sorry, in the PHP it does say order by the meta_value and it does work for everything else, it's just these two people that it doesn't order correctly due to their punctuated surname.

Comment: You could store names with an `'` in a temp array, remove the the `'` then sort the data. After it has been sorted, re-add the `'`. Might not be the best solution but it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a bit of a mistake on our end, the surname were as follows:
O'Koren
O’Brien

O’Brien has an acute accent rather than a apostrophe and so was last in the order.